# SQL INSERT SELECT ordenado

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

He creado una tabla temporal `@TablaTurno`, el cual le inserto datos de la siguiente forma:

```
insert @TablaTurno
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tturno)+@idturno as IDTurno,mci.IDCaja as IDCaja,@idestado as IDEstado,@idlocal as IDLocal,...
...order by ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tturno) asc
```

Luego

```
insert MC_VENTAS.dbo.MCCDC_TURNO
select * from @TablaTurno
```

Y los datos me salen desordenados, p.e.(al hacer `SELECT` a `MC_VENTAS.dbo.MCCDC_TURNO`)

```
17
18
19
20
21
.
.
.
93
94
95
111
112
113
```

Pero al hacer el `SELECT` a la tabla `@TablaTurno`, sí aparece ordenado. ¿Qué puedo hacer?, puesto que necesito que en mi tabla `MC_VENTAS.dbo.MCCDC_TURNO` aparezca ordenado.

---

Si hago el `SELECT` a `@TablaTurno` me lista así:

```
1
2
3
.
.
.
```

Si hago `SELECT` a `MC_VENTAS.dbo.MCCDC_TURNO` me sale así:

```
17
18
19
.
.
.
1
```

Y `MC_VENTAS.dbo.MCCDC_TURNO` se llena de `@tablaturno`. ¿Por qué se desordena?

Comment: esos datos no se ven desordenados. De todas formas, no existe un orden inherente en las tablas, si necesitas que aparezcan ordenados, entonces la única forma es usar `ORDER BY`

Comment: @Lamak: En realidad, por mas sencillo y obvio que parezca, lo que dices es la única respuesta correcta a su pregunta. ¿Pudieras mover el comentario como respuesta para que la pregunta no quede abierta innecesariamente?

Comment: @sstan antes de responder, me gustaría que op clarificara el por qué dice que los datos están desordenados en primer lugar, para no dejar una respuesta que puede estar incorrecta

Comment: Si hago el select ah @TablaTurno me lista asi 
1
2
3
.
.
.

Answer (score 1):

> los datos me salen desordenados, p.e.(al hacer `SELECT` a `MC_VENTAS.dbo.MCCDC_TURNO`)

Esto no es ningún defecto. Como bien dice la documentación oficial de SQL Server bajo el tema de la [claúsula `ORDER BY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188385(v=sql.110).aspx):

> El orden en que se devuelven las filas en un conjunto de resultados ***no se puede garantizar***, a menos que se especifique una cláusula `ORDER BY`.

Esta es una verdad sumamente sencilla, pero que por una razón que aún no me explico, muchos resisten. Si quieres obtener resultados ordenados, la ***única*** manera de garantizarlo es por medio de agregarle un `ORDER BY` a tu consulta.

> Pero al hacer el `SELECT` a la tabla `@TablaTurno` sí aparece ordenado

No importa. No te dejes engañar. Aunque parezca que logres obtener resultados ordenados sin la claúsula `ORDER BY` con ciertas consultas, y aunque parezca que los resultados se mentienen ordenados aún al ejecutar la misma consulta varias veces, ¡es un engaño! ¡No caigas en la trampa!

Hay una cantidad de factores que pueden hacer que, en el momento que menos lo anticipes, el orden de tus resultados puede cambiar. Y si eso llegara a suceder, habrá sido tu culpa. Porque la documentación te dice más que claramente que no puedes asumir ningún orden a menos que le agregues un `ORDER BY` a tu consulta.

> ¿qué puedo hacer?, puesto que necesito que en mi tabla `MC_VENTAS.dbo.MCCDC_TURNO` aparezca ordenado

Para énfasis, la única respuesta correcta a esa pregunta es: efectúa tu consulta con un `ORDER BY`.

---

**¿Cómo puedo reducir el costo de usar un `ORDER BY`?**

Esta si es una mejor pregunta. Por ejemplo, si deseas consultar los datos de la tabla ordenados por `IDTurno`, *pero con buen rendimiento*, es buena idea que tengas un índice definido en la columna `IDTurno`.

Es más, si lo defines como el *índice clúster* de tu tabla, nota el efecto que tiene según la [documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms190457.aspx):

> Los índices clúster ***ordenan*** y almacenan las filas de los datos de la tabla o vista de acuerdo con los valores de la clave del índice.

O sea que si defines `IDTurno` como el *índice clúster* de tu tabla, esto tiene por efecto de ordenar los datos de la tabla por los valores de `IDTurno`, lo que hace que no cueste nada aplicar un `ORDER BY IdTurno` a tu consulta, porque los registros ya están ordenados.

Pero, un momento... ¿cómo es eso de que el *índice clúster* ordena los registros de la tabla por `IdTurno`? ¿No acabamos de decir que los registros siempre están desordenados, y que por eso es necesario especificar la claúsula `ORDER BY`? ¿Es una contradicción?

No es una contradicción. Aunque sí es posible afectar el orden de almacenamiento de los registros de la tabla por medio del índice clúster, esto no garantiza el orden de los registros al momento de hacer la consulta. Puede que lo haga, pero el punto es que no hay garantía que lo haga. Una vez más, la única manera de garantizar el orden de registros en una consulta es usando la claúsula `ORDER BY`.